# What does the phrase "tag up arenas" mean here?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, phrases, phrasal-verbs

I am finding it difficult to figure out the meaning of the phrase "tag up arenas" in the following sentence from the description of the game "Subway Surfers":

*Grind, skate, and **tag up arenas**.*

For some context, here is a description of the text from [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/subwaysurfers/):

In the game, players take the role of young graffiti artists who, upon being caught in the act of applying graffiti to ("tagging") a metro railway site, where they run through the railroad tracks to escape from the inspector and his dog.

Based on the description, I assume that the phrase "tag up" means "make graffiti in arenas". I have never come across the phrase "tag up" before.

Comment: You have understood the phrase correctly, so I'm not sure what your question is.  It might be useful to note that "*verb* **up**" is a very common structure - *drink up*, *add up*, *mark up*, *warm up*, etc. - that often implies "*verb* to completion".

Comment: @stangdon Your comment confirms my observation, and this was the objective of my question. Being a non-native speaker, I was looking for this confirmation.